# can't enable Nested VT-x and amd-v in virtualbox

Tags: virtual-machine

In Viritualbox Manager i can't enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V
I have lenovo p14s with cpu AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 6850U and BIOS VERSION R23ET60W

i need it to run nexus ios in the eve ng.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XTX3.png)